# Designing a Calendar View

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a view like the calendar in the image below, but I don't know where to start. I would like to find the best approach for this. I thought about the GridView but it did not work out. Does anyone have any suggestions, please?

[image]

Comment: I updated my answer with a concept of what you could do to make your calendar work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not offer any calendar view in the SDK. That is a big loss from the developer’s point of view. There are lots of situations where it would be beneficial to display days of a month and provide some option for the user to choose the day.

One solution is to use a 3rd party component. The second one is to implement one by your own

check these links, would be helpful to you

http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/

and this

http://caughtinthemobileweb.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/how-to-implement-calendarview-in-android/

Answer (score 2):

Use a grid layout with a linear layout header. You can use the GridLayout to implement click commands, and using some fancy adapter work you can manage the days of the week / month.

Edit:

Here is a rough concept of what you could do and how GridView will work for you.

```
class CalendarView extends LinearLayout {

    public CalendarView (Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        mHeader = new LinearLayout(context);
        mHeader.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        addView(mHeader);
        // Add in your days, shouldn't be too bad, they are just text views.

        mCalendar = new GridView(context);
        mCalendar.setColumns(mHeader.getNumViews()); // You could hard code this.
        mCalendar.setAdapterView(new CalendarAdapter());
        addView(mCalendar);
    }

    // ... Other contructors


    private class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        // Override methods, this should be too bad.

        @Override public view getView (int pos, View convert, ViewGroup parent) {
            ListView lv = (ListView)convert;
            if (convert == null)
                lv = new ListView(parent.getContext());

            // Here you will need to figure out some way of
            // determining the date.

            CalendarDate app = (CalendarDate)lv.getTag();

            // Determine if this view is already set to the correct date,
            // if not rest the list view

            app.sort();

            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(parent.getContext(), R.layout.datelistview, app.getDates());
        }
    }

    public static class CalendarDate {
        List<Appointment> mDates = new ArrayList<Appointment>();

        public void addAppointment(Appointment app) {
            mDate.add(app);
        }

        // ... and the rest of your methods (getters and state returns)
    }

    public Appointment implements Compareable<Appointment> {
        private Date mDate;

        private String mName;   // Appointment name
        private String mDesc;   // Appointment description

        @Override public int compareTo(Appointment to) {
            return mDate.compareTo(mDate);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy for your answer.I was looking for a calendar in which I can mark some events on the date of the calendar. I got the sample code from the link provided by Avi Kumar Manku which provide me the solution I was looking for. You were very supportive.thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the horizontal LinearLayout into the vertical LinearLayout with all textview with the same weight.

```
 android:layout_weight="1"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="sun" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="mon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="tue" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="wed" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="thu" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="fri" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="sat" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="sun" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="mon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="tue" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="wed" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="thu" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="fri" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="sat" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Refer to my comments about Agarwal's answer.